# Update input field number after counting checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I'm making a form and I'm counting the check boxes that are checked yes or no using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519659/count-the-number-of-checked-check-boxes-and-display-them-on-a-fixed-div-using-jq) as a guide. I can get the number but it doesn't show in the input field. I see it update looking at the code with firebug. Here's my cut down test code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[value=Yes]").each(function () {
        $(this).change(updateCountyes);
        });
updateCountyes();
    function updateCountyes () {
    var countyes = $("input[value=Yes]:checked").size();
    $("input#item11_number_1").text(countyes);
    $("label#item11").toggle(countyes > 0);
    };
    $("input[value=No]").each(function () {
    $(this).change(updateCountno);
    });
updateCountno();
    function updateCountno () {
    var countno = $("input[value=No]:checked").size();
    $("input#item12_number_1").text(countno);
    $("label#item12").toggle(countno > 0);
    };
    });</script>  
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox"  value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="checkbox"  value="No" />No
<input type="checkbox"  value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="checkbox"  value="No" />No
<div id="item11" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column">
    <div class="fb-grouplabel">
      <label style="display: inline;" id="item11_label_0">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="fb-input-number">
      <input type="number" autocomplete="off" data-hint="" placeholder="" step="1" max="999999999" min="0" id="item11_number_1" name="countyes">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="item12" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column">
    <div class="fb-grouplabel">
      <label style="display: inline;" id="item12_label_0">No</label>
    </div>
    <div class="fb-input-number">
      <input type="number" autocomplete="off" data-hint="" step="1" max="999999999" min="0" id="item12_number_1" name="countno">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For inputs you want to use `val` ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)) not `text`.  So change these lines:

```
$("input#item11_number_1").text(countyes);
$("input#item12_number_1").text(countno);
```

To this:

```
$("input#item11_number_1").val(countyes);
$("input#item12_number_1").val(countno);
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yTsG9/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Works great now!

Comment: @Progrower Great, glad to hear.  Here on StackOverflow you can accept an answer as the correct one by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.