# JS Function declarations should not be placed in block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, jshint, javascript-function-declaration

I have wrapped 95% of the `'parentCtrl'` (Controller) within an `'IF'` statement, this prevents any functions from triggering if the user isn't signed in and authorized. Since doing this I keep getting the following JSHint error!

**Error**
JSHint 104:5 Function declarations should not be placed in block?

[image]

If I remove the `'IF'` statement the error goes away!

Advice on how to fix this would be helpful!

**IF Statement**

```
if($scope.user){}
```

**Controller JS**

```
var fittingControllers = angular.module('fittingControllers',[]);
// 1. Parent Controller
fittingControllers.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$localStorage', '$filter', '$timeout', 'Notification', '$sce', '$state', function($scope, Auth, $localStorage, $filter, $timeout, Notification, $sce, $state) {
  //// Setup Authentication
  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.user = $scope.auth.$getAuth();
  //// Facebook Login
  $scope.facebookLogin = function() {
    var scope = {scope: 'email,user_birthday'};
    $scope.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook', scope).then(function(auth){
      $state.go('main.statistics');
    })['catch'](function (error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
  //// Authentication Functions
  if($scope.user){
    //// Facebook Provider
    if($scope.user.provider === 'facebook'){
      //// Facebook Data
      $scope.uid = $scope.user.uid;
      $scope.displayName = $scope.user.facebook.displayName;
      $scope.firstName = $scope.user.facebook.cachedUserProfile.first_name;
      $scope.lastName = $scope.user.facebook.cachedUserProfile.last_name;
      $scope.dob = $scope.user.facebook.cachedUserProfile.birthday;
      $scope.emailAddress = $scope.user.facebook.email;
      $scope.profileImageURL = $scope.user.facebook.profileImageURL;
    }
    //// Password Provider
    else if($scope.user.provider === 'password'){
        //// Password Data TBC
    }
    //// Provider Results
    var uid = $scope.uid;
    var displayName = $scope.displayName;
    var firstName = $scope.firstName;
    var lastName = $scope.lastName;
    var dob = $scope.dob;
    var emailAddress = $scope.emailAddress;
    var profileImageURL = $scope.profileImageURL;
    //// Aditional Data (Test)
    var weddingDate = '21/09/2017';
    var bodyType = 'triangle';
    //// LocalStorage
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage;
    //// $localStorage.$reset();
    //// Storage Data
    if($scope.$storage.app === undefined) {
      $scope.$storage.app = ({
        //// User Account
        'account': [{
          //// User Information
          'userInfo': [
            {'id':uid,'username':displayName,'age':dob,'emailAddress':emailAddress,'telephoneNumber':'','weddingDate':weddingDate,'bodyType':bodyType}
          ]
        },{
          //// User BodyType
          'bodyInfo': [
            {'height':524,'chest':32,'waist':30,'hips':32,'thighs':20,'BodyType':''}
          ]
        },{
          //// User Love List
          'lovelist': [
            {'heart': [],'brokenheart': []}
          ]
        }],
        //// App Settings
        'settings': [{
          'introMsg': [
            {'lovelist': false},
            {'showStyle': false},
            {'secondOpionion': false}
          ]
        },{
          'introBtn': [
            {'lovelist': false},
            {'showStyle': false},
            {'secondOpionion': false}
          ]
        }],
        //// App Data
        'courtyard': [{
          //// Dress Collection
          'dresses': [
            {'id':'1','name':'Ritva Westenius 1','designer':'Ritva Westenius 2','description':'Pellentesque ultricies, sem vel pellentesque tempus, quam massa posuere mauris, gravida semper massa ante non risus. Ut scelerisque hendrerit arcu, ac scelerisque mi maximus in. Sed non bibendum sapien, ut blandit purus. Aenean a scelerisque mauris. Pellentesque augue augue, feugiat et dignissim sit amet, rhoncus sit amet metus.','bodyType': 'triangle','imageURL': '../img/dress1-body-small@2x.jpg'},
            {'id':'2','name':'Stephanie Allin 1','designer':'Stephanie Allin 2','description':'Vivamus mattis posuere eleifend. Etiam vitae mauris neque. Sed at quam quis felis elementum mattis eu id diam.','bodyType':'triangle','imageURL':'../img/dress1-body-medium@2x.jpg'},
            {'id':'3','name':'Allure Bridals 1','designer':'Allure Bridals 2','description':'Phasellus lorem urna, blandit in vestibulum vel, consectetur nec ipsum. Pellentesque tellus ipsum, tincidunt eget arcu euismod, vestibulum molestie dui.','bodyType':'round','imageURL': '../img/dress1-body-large@2x.jpg'},
            {'id':'10','name':'Pronovias Barcelona 1','designer':'Pronovias Barcelona 2','description': 'Vestibulum libero odio, suscipit vitae aliquam in, maximus eu purus. Morbi luctus elit nec elit euismod iaculis. Ut mi nisi, dignissim quis libero id, sagittis rhoncus leo. Pellentesque placerat mi non nunc tincidunt vestibulum. Suspendisse in ornare tortor.','bodyType':'triangle','imageURL':'../img/dress1-body-large@2x.jpg'},
            {'id':'11','name':'Chanticleer 1','designer':'Chanticleer 2','description':'Nulla ante mi, commodo vitae diam sed, aliquam consectetur ex. In maximus nisl urna, non aliquet leo finibus et. Donec rhoncus ipsum eget elementum accumsan. Nullam id tellus in magna molestie facilisis quis et tellus. Nunc nec feugiat ipsum.','bodyType':'triangle','imageURL':'../img/dress1-body-small@2x.jpg'},
            {'id':'7','name':'Alan Hannah 1','designer':'Alan Hannah 2','description':'Etiam non sagittis nisl. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque sed dolor vitae sem molestie interdum. Praesent leo lectus, cursus ac bibendum quis, accumsan in metus. Phasellus sagittis, lectus eget iaculis molestie, magna tortor fringilla neque, sit amet ultrices nunc erat sed augue.','bodyType':'triangle','imageURL':'../img/dress1-body-large@2x.jpg'}
          ]
        }]
      });
    } else {
      $scope.$storage.app = $scope.$storage.app;
    }
    //// Notification Function
    function notification(){
      $timeout(function(){
        Notification.bethan(
          {message:'Hi '+firstName+'! you’re not sure what to do? Hover the menu in the top right and click',positionY:'bottom',positionX:'left',delay:10000,templateUrl:"views/notification.html"}
        );
      }, 3000);
      $timeout(function() {
        Notification.rhiannon(
          {message:'This dress is perfect for a Triangle body shape like yours!',positionY:'bottom',positionX:'left',delay:null,templateUrl:"views/notification.html"}
        );
      }, 6000);
    }
    //// Alert Function
    function alertMessage(id) {
      //// Message ID
      var messageID = id;
      //// Alert Collection
      var messages = {
        "results": [
          {'id':'1','icon':'','button':true,'title':'Welcome','subtitle':'Hi '+firstName+', welcome to the Virtual Fitting room','content':'Here you will be able to browse through a selection of our dresses<br/>and shortlist them for future refrence. To help us find the best<br/>dress for you, please let us know a bit about yourself'},
          {'id':'2','icon':'','button':false,'title':'Raiding the Rails','subtitle':'','content':'From the measurments you have supplied, we see you have a triangle body shape.<br/>Please wait while we get together the 5 best dresses for your shape.'},
          {'id':'3','icon':'','button':false,'title':'My Love List','subtitle':'','content':'Any dresses you mark with a &#9829; will store<br/> into your Love list you can review at any<br/> point by clicking the heart icon.'},
          {'id':'4','icon':'','button':false,'title':'Show me the Style','subtitle':'','content':'Feel free to look through the rest of our<br/> collection and &#9829; any that you like.'},
          {'id':'5','icon':'','button':false,'title':'Second Optionions','subtitle':'','content':'It can be tough to choose, so why not ask<br/> the ones who know you best to help<br/>by voting for their favourites.'}
        ]
      };
      var messageResult = $filter('filter')(messages.results, {id: messageID})[0];
      var message = '<h2>'+messageResult.title+'</h2><h3>'+messageResult.subtitle+'</h3><p>'+messageResult.content+'</p>';
      $scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml(message);
      $scope.showMessage = {active: true};
      //// Close Alert
      $scope.hideMessage = function() {
        $scope.showMessage.active = !$scope.showMessage.active;
        notification();
      };
      $scope.hideButton = {active: true};
      if (messageResult.button === true) {
        $scope.hideButton.active = !$scope.hideButton.active;
      }
    }
    alertMessage(1);
    //// Child Alert
    $scope.$on('eventName', function(event, args) {
      var getBodyType = $scope.$storage.app.account[0].userInfo[0].bodyType;
      var getID = $filter('filter')($scope.$storage.app.courtyard[0].dresses,{bodyType: getBodyType})[0].id;
      $scope.id = args.id;
      alertMessage($scope.id);
      $timeout(function() {
        if ($scope.id === 2) {
          $state.go('main.rail', {id: getID});
        } else if ($scope.id === 3) {}
      }, 3000);
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.showMessage = {active: false};
      }, 6000);
    });
    //// Menu Function
    function menu(){
      $scope.hidden = false;
      //// Menu Collection
      $scope.items = [
        {name: 'Help',icon: 'svg/help.svg',direction: 'left',backgroundColor: 'rgb(239, 149, 73)'},
        {name: 'Book',icon: 'svg/book.svg',direction: 'left',backgroundColor: 'rgb(95, 205, 155)'},
        {name: 'Contact',icon: 'svg/contact.svg',direction: 'left',backgroundColor:'rgb(32, 133, 188)'},
        {name: 'Share',icon: 'svg/share.svg',direction: 'left',backgroundColor: 'rgb(102, 181, 215)'},
        {name: 'Exit',icon: 'svg/exit.svg',direction: 'left',backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 206, 97)'}
      ];
    }
    menu();
    //// Menu Triggers
    $scope.menuButton = function(button) {
      if (button === 'Help') {
        alert('Help');
      } else if (button === 'Book') {
        alert('Book');
      } else if (button === 'Contact') {
        alert('Contact');
      } else if (button === 'Share') {
        alert('Share');
      } else if (button === 'Exit') {
        //// Remove Notifications
        Notification.clearAll();
        //// Unauthenticate
        $scope.auth.$unauth();
        //// State Change
        $timeout(function() {
          //// Remove Notifications (Again)
          Notification.clearAll();
          //// State Change
          $state.go('authentication');
        }, 3000);
      }
    };
    //// App Buttons (Love List, Show me the Style (Collection) & Second Opinion)
    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return angular.toJson([$scope.$storage.app.settings[1].introBtn[0]]);
    }, function() {
      if ($scope.$storage.app.settings[1].introBtn[0].lovelist === true) {
        $scope.loveListBtn = true;
      }
      if ($scope.$storage.app.settings[1].introBtn[0].showStyle === true) {
        $scope.showStyleBtn = true;
      }
      if ($scope.$storage.app.settings[1].introBtn[0].secondOpionion === true) {
        $scope.secondOpionionBtn = true;
      }
    });
    //// View Navigator (Pager)
    $scope.pager = function(url) {$state.go(url);};
  }
  //// Authentication End
}]);
```

Comment: Related: [Function declarations inside if/else statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10069204/218196) and [May function declarations appear inside statements in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4071292/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all your `function` definition outside `if` block

```
function notification()

function alertMessage(id)

function menu()
```

JavaScript does not have block scoping, it has only **function scope**. So, it does not matter if you write function definition inside if block or not, it is available throughout the enclosing function block.

Thus JSHint throws that error, as it might give ambiguous meaning to reader that function is only available within `if` block

Because of **hoisting** it does not matter if you put function *declaration* after its call/use within the same function block.

Comment: Thanks for this @kulbhushan!

Comment: mark it as Answer, as it may help other community members, I'm glad that it helped you

Comment: *"So, it does not matter if you write function definition inside if block or not, it is available throughout the enclosing function block."* That's actually not true. According to ES5, function *declarations* are forbidden in blocks. However, browsers implement different behavior: Chrome hoists them, Firefox treats them similar to function expressions. I think ES6 solved this but I don't know in which way.

Comment: E.g. this behaves differently in Chrome and Firefox: `foo(); if(false) { function foo() { console.log('hello chrome'); } }` .