# Why JavaScript function declaration behave differently in chrome and safari?

Tags: javascript

```js
    foo();

    if (true) {
      function foo() {
        console.log(1);
      }
    } else {
      function foo() {
        console.log(2)
      }
    }
```

In chrome it shows Uncaught TypeError,but In safari it shows 2.

Comment: Those function definitions won't be hoisted so I'd expect it to be an Uncaught Type Error in any environment. Running the code snippet also yields that error

Comment: Don't we have already good QA on this problem ? I don't find them

Comment: @RobG Can you elaborate a bit or link to the part of the spec you are referring?

Comment: @jakeehoffmann—gimme a bit of time…

Comment: The essence of the problem is that this kind of function declarations in inner blocs (i.e. not at the scope level) always gave different results depending on the browser. It's now just forbidden.

Comment: @RobG I'd be tempted to close using that QA but I'm not sure enough it's the good decision to use my hammer without confirmation

Comment: @DenysSéguret—agree, there are other questions with good answers too but they're hard to find. My memory on this issue isn't great, it was topical for a while but not recently.

Comment: @RobG I tried to find already good QA on this problem,but I did not find one.

Comment: A relevant reference is in [*ECMA-262 ed 5 Appendix B.3.3 Block-Level Function Declarations Web Legacy Compatibility Semantics*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics). I think that since then it's been incorporated into the body of the spec. They [*aren't allowed in strict mode*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarations-in-ifstatement-statement-clauses).

Comment: @RobG You already gave good references. Please write a clean answer explaining that 1) it was bad 2) it's now clearly forbidden.

Comment: This is a surprisingly good question

Answer (score 7):

This behaviour has some history. In the beginning (let's say ECMA-262 ed 3, which was the first real version of the spec) function declarations weren't permitted inside blocks (see [Kangax, *Function statements*](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#expr-vs-decl)).

However, IE just treated them as function declarations and "hoisted" them, while Mozilla browsers (maybe Netscape Navigator) conditionally evaluated them as function statements, an allowed extension to the specification. Some other browsers threw an error, which is probably what they should have done.

That range of behaviours was pretty intolerable so with ECMA-262 ed 5 aka ES5, function statements were formalised in an appendix (they were better explained in the next version, ECMAScript 2015 [Appendix B.3.3 Block-Level Function Declarations Web Legacy Compatibility Semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics)). This was probably part of the push to document what various implementations do rather than trying to rigidly enforce particular behaviour that was contrary to intent but not the letter of the spec.

To fix things, function statements were prohibited in strict mode, which was also introduced with ECMAScript ed 5.

For additional reading, see [*May function declarations appear inside statements in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071292/may-function-declarations-appear-inside-statements-in-javascript) for a good Q&A from about the time of Ed 5.

The bottom line is that if you want to conditionally "declare" a function, use function expressions, which avoid all issues with function statements as they are consistently treated by all implementations:

```
var someFn;

if (something) {
  someFn = function(...params1) {/*statement list 1*/};

} else {
  someFn = function(...params2) {/*statement list 2*/};   
}
```

There is a discussion on this topic on [comp.lang.javascript: *FAQ Topic - What is a function statement?*](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.javascript/Ywb2kQPtU5g/discussion) from May 2010. Mostly read the exchanges between  Juriy "kangax" Zaytsev and Richard Cornford, e.g.

Kangax:

> … You mean -- it doesn't matter -- whether it is
>   a function declaration (which is created on entering the
>   context) or a function statement (which the same as function
>   expression and created by the Function constructor is created
>   at code execution), i.e. both of them can be treated as just
>   an allowed extension?

Cornford:

> Yes, ECMA syntax doesn't allow for either so if they are there they
>   must be extensions. Extensions are allowed so neither can be
>   considered wrong (on the surface, even if IE's treating named function
>   expressions as 'out of context' function declarations, and so
>   potentially producing two function objects, is so unhelpfully odd that
>   it would be better considered a bug than an extension). There has
>   never been any reason for expecting two different ECMAScript
>   implementations to have the same extensions, so there is no reason for
>   expecting the same non-(ECMA)standard syntax to result in the same
>   behaviour in two different environments. (Of course if an environment
>   claims to be JavaScript(tm) compatible in addition to being ECMAScript
>   compatible then it should be reproducing the extensions found in
>   JavaScript(tm)).

Which pretty much answers the question and notes why function statements should be avoided.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8871974/218196 to me, though your answer is more elaborate.

Comment: @FelixKling—yes, agree with that. I wasn't aware of that duplicate.