# Function declaration inside conditional

Tags: javascript, hoisting

In a book *[You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch4.md)* There is this sample of code I don't understand fully.

*"Function declarations that appear inside of normal blocks typically hoist to the enclosing scope, rather than being conditional as this code implies:"*

```
foo(); // "b"

var a = true;
if (a) {
   function foo() { console.log( "a" ); }
}
else {
   function foo() { console.log( "b" ); }
}
```

What does it mean? How is it even possible? Is the conditional not working?

Comment: The quoted statement is not correct.

Comment: *"What does it mean?"* It means that function declarations are hoisted just like everywhere else. *"Is the conditional not working?"* It is working, but hoisting happens before any code is executed. It's actually more complicated then that because function *declarations* inside blocks are actually invalid. Yet browsers allowed them and implement different behaviors. See [Why are function declarations handled differently in different browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8871974/218196)

Comment: if you did `var a = true; const foo = a ? () => console.log('a') : () => console.log('b'); foo();` Then the console would log 'a' because `foo` wouldn't be hoisted.

Comment: Also see [*Why are function declarations handled differently in different browsers?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871974/why-are-function-declarations-handled-differently-in-different-browsers).

Comment: @RobG I disagree with your duplicate marking. He is clearly not asking about browser differences. He did not understand function hoisting.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because function declarations are moved to the top of the file by the javascript parser. That's what they mean by hoisting. The last declaration of `foo` overwrites the first when they are hoisted.

Comment: Your explanation is incorrect. Function declarations were not allowed inside blocks, so some browsers "hoisted" them, some didn't (treating them as function statements, an extension to ECMA-262) and some threw errors. The behaviour has been more or less standardised in the current spec, but their use is discouraged. See the [*duplicate link*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135925/why-javascript-function-declaration-behave-differently-in-chrome-and-safari).

Comment: @RobG - That's not correct. Please see the section on this page about function hosting:
http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting

Comment: In particular, on that page, you can search for `isItHoisted` and look at the function and the explanation accompanying.

Comment: @RobG The answer in that duplicate link is different than this person's question...

Comment: @ChipDean have you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135925/why-javascript-function-declaration-behave-differently-in-chrome-and-safari#answer-43136985) though?

Comment: @Josp So you are saying You don't know JS is wrong?It's saying exactly what I'm saying here: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch4.md

Comment: @Josep Here is the line from that page: While multiple/duplicate var declarations are effectively ignored, subsequent function declarations do override previous ones.

Comment: @ChipDean I was just asking if you actually read [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135925/why-javascript-function-declaration-behave-differently-in-chrome-and-safari#answer-43136985). I'm asking that because until 5 minutes ago I would have thought that your answer is completely accurate. After reading that one though I feel that's a more complete answer, therefore more accurate... Also, no point arguing here, since this is a duplicate question. Maybe you should elaborate your answer better in the original question.

Comment: I'm well aware of "hoisting". There is nothing in your linked article about function statements, which is what the OP is about. If the section of code is not treated as a function declaration, then it isn't "hoisted", which is why there are different behaviours in different browsers.

Comment: @RobG Umm he's asking about function declarations, which is what the linked article is about. Did you even look at it?

Comment: @Josep i can't respond on that question because it's different than this one. He's clearly not asking about browser differences.