# JavaScript function declaration hoisting from within loops

Tags: javascript

If we put function declaration inside `for` loop — its name will be hoisted, but it will contain `undefined`:

```js
console.log(foo, bar); //undefined function bar() {}

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  function foo() {}
}

function bar() {};
```

Why is it like that? It is told everywhere that `var` gets hoisted, leaving initialization in place, and that function declarations are fully hoisted. Seems like some specification quirk but it is curious why it works this way

Comment: Hoisting 101...

Comment: @epascarello—I think it's more do to with function declarations/statements inside blocks, which has always been problematic and hence should be avoided.

Comment: Back compat. It shouldn't be hoisted to function scope at all in plain ES6.

Comment: Also see [*Why JavaScript function declaration behave differently in chrome and safari?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135925/why-javascript-function-declaration-behave-differently-in-chrome-and-safari) This behaves differently in different browsers, there is also [*Why are function declarations handled differently in different browsers?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871974/why-are-function-declarations-handled-differently-in-different-browsers)

Comment: The issue is one of historical browser _incompatabilty_ rather than _compatability_. MDN suggest ["Don't do it"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Block-level_functions_in_non-strict_code) in regards block level functions in non strict mode. Strict mode has issues as well: inside a for loop a new, different, function object is created for function _declarations_ during each iteration of the loop.