# SetInterval can't see functions in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, setinterval

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. I am using the below code to get an image to slide onto the screen and 2 more images to appear one after the other. This works fine for Chrome and IE 7-9. Unfortunately, on Firefox I get an error saying:

> move is not defined [ mover = setInterval(move, 1000); ]

My Code:

```
//define variables
var mover = 0
var bubble1move = 0
var bubble2move = 0


if(mover != 0)
{//interval is finished
    function move ()
    {   
        console.log("moving")
        clearInterval(mover)
        var moving_img = document.getElementById("i_sliding_image")
        var left = 0
        function frame() 
        {       
            left -= 2  // update parameters
            moving_img.style.left = left + 'px'// show frame
            if (left == -274) // check finish condition
            {
                clearInterval(id)                   
                bubble1move = setInterval(function() {bubble1()}, 2000);
            }
        }
        var id = setInterval(frame, 10) // draw every 10ms
    }       
}
if(bubble1move != 0)
{//interval is finished
    function bubble1()
    {
        clearInterval(bubble1move);     
        document.getElementById("img-bubble1").style.zIndex = "1";
        bubble2move = setInterval(function() {bubble2()}, 2000);
    }
}
if(bubble2move != 0)
{//interval is finished
    function bubble2()
    {
        clearInterval(bubble2move)
        var vBubble2 = document.getElementById("img-bubble2").style
        vBubble2.zIndex = "1";
    }
}
window.onload = function initialiser()
{
    mover = setInterval(move, 1000);//initial time to animation
}
```

All getElementByIds are getting div tags containing the images.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Should your definition of move be inside the if statement? Try defining the function elsewhere and simply calling it from inside the if.

Comment: Where are all your statement terminators? `;`

Comment: Thanks agryson, that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your function outside of the `if`. There is no reason for it to be within the `if`. It doesn't work on Firefox because of the way Firefox interprets functions (differently to other browsers).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069100/why-cant-i-use-a-javascript-function-before-its-definition-inside-a-try-block) for more info.

Thanks to @freakish for the link.

Comment: This is incorrect: it doesn't work on FireFox, because FireFox interpretes `function` stetements a bit differently then other browsers ( under Chrome wherever you define function it will be always visible ). Read this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069100/why-cant-i-use-a-javascript-function-before-its-definition-inside-a-try-block It solves the problem, so I won't give -1, but I won't give +1 as well.

Comment: @freakish, thanks - added to answer. The solution remains the same though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are initializing your mover variable at the begining of your js to 0 and your if statement is only declaring the function if `mover != 0`. Initialize `mover = 1;` or take your function outside of the if statement(recommended). You're just trying to call `move()` before it exists