# ReferenceError: function parseXml undefined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-mobile, undefined-reference

I am getting this strange error even when `parseXml` is **defined**. The piece of code works `fine in Chrome` but NOT in `Firefox`.

```
   $(document).on("pageinit", "#map-page", function () {
       var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(56.8517843, 14.828458); // Default somewhere to Växjö when no geolocation support
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
           var stations = [];
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "busstations.xml",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: parseXml
           });

           function parseXml(xml) {
               $(xml).find('station').each(function () {
                   var name = $(this).find("name").text();
                   var localurl = $(this).find("localurl").text();
                   var latitude = $(this).find("latitude").text();
                   var longitude = $(this).find("longitude").text();
                   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {
                       maximumAge: 500000,
                       enableHighAccuracy: true,
                       timeout: 6000
                   });

                   function success(pos) {
                       currentLatitude = pos.coords.latitude;
                       currentLongitude = pos.coords.longitude;
                       console.log(pos.coords.latitude + " " + pos.coords.longitude);

                   }

                   function fail(error) {
                       alert("No GL support!");
                   }

                   stations.push({
                       "name": name,
                       "localurl": localurl
                   });
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(stations));


               });
           }
       }
   });
```

However if I remove the **if(navigator.geolocation)** check condition on the 3rd line, then it also works fine in Firefox and there is also no such undefined `ReferenceError`.

Also if I bring this **if(navigator.geolocation)** check condition inside the `parseXml` function, the code works fine. Wonder what is causing the problem in `Firefox`.

Comment: what is the error and on which line?

Comment: If I hit F12 and enter alert(navigator.geolocation) in Fx20X I get a geolocation object

Comment: I changed the title...it apparently says : ReferenceError: parseXml is not defined

success: parseXml

Comment: Did you try to define the `parseXml` function before the `if` or the ajax call?

Comment: @JonathanNaguin: The `parseXml` function is defined after the `if` and the `ajax` call.

Comment: my guess is that Chrome scans the script once to compile it into bytecodes or whatever and firefox does not. so it works in Chrome.

Comment: What happens if you take the parseXml outside all the functions?

Comment: @Suyesh that is the point that JonathanNaguin is making. define it BEFORE.

Comment: Yes if the `parseXml` is defined before the `if` and the `ajax` call, it works fine in Firefox as well. @JonathanNaguin: If you post as an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that Firefox deals a little different with function declarations inside conditionals statments. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression) says:

> Note: Although this kind of function looks like a function
>   declaration, it is actually an expression (or statement), since it is
>   nested within another statement. See differences between function
>   declarations and function expressions.

So if it is an expression then when the `ajax` call try to use it the function is not defined yet.

To fix it change the order of the declaration or declare the function outside.

---

This is covered also in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069100/why-cant-i-use-a-javascript-function-before-its-definition-inside-a-try-block).

Answer (score 1):

Is this acceptable and working?

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#map-page", function () {
   var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(56.8517843, 14.828458); // Default somewhere to Växjö when no geolocation support
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "busstations.xml",
           dataType: "xml",
           success: parseXml
       });
   }
 });


function parseXml(xml) {
   var stations = [];
   $(xml).find('station').each(function () {
   var name = $(this).find("name").text();
   var localurl = $(this).find("localurl").text();
   var latitude = $(this).find("latitude").text();
   var longitude = $(this).find("longitude").text();
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
     function(pos) {
       currentLatitude = pos.coords.latitude;
       currentLongitude = pos.coords.longitude;
       console.log(pos.coords.latitude + " " + pos.coords.longitude);
     },
     function(error) {
      alert("No GL support!");
     }, 
     {
       maximumAge: 500000,
       enableHighAccuracy: true,
       timeout: 6000
     }
   );
   stations.push({
     "name": name,
     "localurl": localurl
   });
   console.log(JSON.stringify(stations));
 });
}
```

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly. +1 for bringing `var stations = [];` inside the `parseXml` function as well. `Jonathan Naguin` answered it first in the comment. So I will take his answer. Thanks..:)