# Javascript function hoisting inside of if statements

Tags: javascript, hoisting

What's the deal with javascript function hoisting inside of `if` statements?  Does js just not do it?  The following code, when run in a browser works just fine.  It will alert "hey" after two seconds.

```
<script>
setTimeout(hey,2000)
function hey(){
    alert('hey')
}
</script>
```

But add a trival `if` statement around this:

```
<script>
if(true){
setTimeout(hey,2000)

function hey(){
    alert('hey')
}
}
</script>
```

and suddenly it complains that `hey is not defined`.
Now if you change the callback from `hey` to `function(){hey()}`, like this:

```
<script>
if(true){
setTimeout(function(){hey()},2000)

function hey(){
    alert('hey')
}
}
</script>
```

then it starts working again, even with the if statement.  So what's going on?

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/7omodL3z/) the problem you describe.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r1oc1joh/ JFiddle accepts it.

Comment: I'm using firefox.  You can just cut and paste that code directly into a file without any other code and it happened to me.

Comment: Both worked here ... http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/3807s37n/1/.  Just tried it in Firefox with no issues.

Comment: Worked for me as well.  I think you must have run some different code than what you pasted here to cause that error :)

Comment: Don't put function declarations in `if` statements anyway.

Comment: Exact duplicate, but I already used my close-vote on "cannot reproduce" before I realized this was a FF-specific problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069100/why-cant-i-use-a-javascript-function-before-its-definition-inside-a-try-block

Comment: @rfornal You totally broke the examples by running them together. You can't do that, or the second `hey`, outside the `if (true) { }` is the one that gets hosted. If you're faithfully copied the code and tried it in Firefox, you'd have found the problem.

Comment: You're right ... only in Firefox ... strange.

Comment: don't declare functions inside conditionals. Just asking for compiler problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Firefox doesn’t hoist function declarations in blocks](http://statichtml.com/2011/spidermonkey-function-hoisting.html), apparently. The behavior you're seeing is specific to Firefox, and documented nearly identically elsewhere.

To paraphrase:

> Works:
>
> ```
> if ( hasRequiredJQueryVersion ) {
>    // Test data here
>    // Library code here
> }
> ```
>
> Works everywhere **except** Firefox:
>
> ```
> if ( true ) {
>     testFunction();
>     function testFunction() {
>         alert(‘testFunction called’);
>     }
> }
> ```

This is behavior you should avoid, as it is specific to Firefox, even though Firefox's behavior may *technically* be correct.

Comment: oh good, I was beginning to think I was crazy with everyone else saying they could't reproduce the problem.  Interestingly, the jsFiddles that people provided still worked on Firefox.  Why would it work in jsFiddle but not work otherwise?

Comment: @J-bob The JSFiddles *don't* work for me in Firefox. None of them do, except the one by rfornal which (I've commented above) is actually broken because they incorrectly reproduced the problem.

Comment: ah yes, I (stupidly) didn't realize that rfornal's jsfiddle wouldn't expose the problem because of how they pasted both exapmles together.

Answer (score -2):

The third example is consistent w/ the second: `setTimeout` isn't actually calling `hey`, so doesn't care that it hasn't been defined.  It is only when the timeout occurs that `hey` is called, by which point is *has* been defined.

Comment: You don't have to call it; `setTimeout` is actually distracting from the real issue which is that Firefox's behavior is broken (or at least, different from every other browser). It isn't hoisting the function.

Comment: OP gave an example where, even though the function wasn't hoisted (as evidenced in the second example), the call worked in the third.  I was only trying to explain that seeming contradiction.  Knock it for not being a complete answer, but it was addressing part of the question (which pointing out the "real issue" does not address).