# Does a Javascript function have to be defined before calling it?

Tags: javascript

If I run the function below before defining it, I will get this error...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: openModal is not defined
```

run  then define

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    delay(openModal, 2000);

    delay = function (f, t) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            f();
        }, t);
    };

    openModal = function () {
        $('#modal-box').css( {
            left: $(window).width() / 2 - $('#modal-box').width() / 2,
            top: $(window).height() / 2 - $('#modal-box').height() / 2
        } );
        $('#modal-box').show();
        $('#modal-mask').show();
    };  

});
```

Now if I define the function first and then call it it works...I have a background in PHP so I am used to being able to access functions globally, am I doing something wrong or do all functions have to be defined before they can be used?

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    delay = function (f, t) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            f();
        }, t);
    };

    openModal = function () {
        $('#modal-box').css( {
            left: $(window).width() / 2 - $('#modal-box').width() / 2,
            top: $(window).height() / 2 - $('#modal-box').height() / 2
        } );
        $('#modal-box').show();
        $('#modal-mask').show();
    };  

    delay(openModal, 2000);

} );
```

Comment: Is that everything, i.e. have you declared the identifier `openModal` (as opposed to defining it) above that scope? e.g. `var openModal;`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript

Comment: @Rup that is the first time openModal is used

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you assign a function to a variable, you have to assign it before you can use the variable to access the function.

If you declare the function with regular syntax instead of assigning it to a variable, it is defined when code is parsed, so this works:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    delay(openModal, 2000);

    function openModal() {
        $('#modal-box').css( {
            left: $(window).width() / 2 - $('#modal-box').width() / 2,
            top: $(window).height() / 2 - $('#modal-box').height() / 2
        } );
        $('#modal-box').show();
        $('#modal-mask').show();
    };  

});
```

(Note the difference in scope, though. When you create the variable `openModal` implicitly by just using it, it will be created in the global scope and will be available to all code. When you declare a function inside another function, it will only be available inside that function. However, you can make the variable local to the function too, using `var openModal = function() {`.)

Answer (score 8):

Move the function definition outside of the document.ready block, and things will work as you expect. In javascript (as in most languages), you must define a function or variable before making a reference to it.

In your first example, you reference `openModal` in the call to `delay()`, but javascript has no way of knowing what `openModal` is yet.

```
openModal = function () {
    $('#modal-box').css( {
        left: $(window).width() / 2 - $('#modal-box').width() / 2,
        top: $(window).height() / 2 - $('#modal-box').height() / 2
    } );
    $('#modal-box').show();
    $('#modal-mask').show();
};

$(document).ready( function() {
    delay(openModal, 2000);
});
```

**edit:**

TJHeuvel points out that `function` does some trickery to define functions before anything else is executed in the same block:
[Why can I use a function before it's defined in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript)

Comment: What's the point of defining the function outside? *"you must define a function [...] before making a reference to it"*: Not necessarily. Since function *declarations* are hoisted, you can define them anywhere and other code in the current scope can call it. Only function *expressions* can be called after they have been assigned.

Comment: Note that what TJHeuvel points out doesn't apply when you assign a function to a variable. Even if the function object itself is created when the code is parsed, it's assigned to the variable at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

I would say, YES. A function always must be defined before calling.
But some functions can be Invoked(called) before where they have been defined (HOISTING)

Two different types of functions that I want to write about are :

Expression Functions & Deceleration Functions

1- Expression Functions: A function expression can be stored in a variable so they do not need function names.They will also named as an anonymous function (a function without a name). To invoke (called) they are always need using a variable name.These kind of functions won't work if calls before where it has been defined which means Hoisting is not happening here. We always must define the expression function first and then invoke it.

```
let lastName = function (family) {
 console.log("My last name is " + family);
};        
let x = lastName("Lopez");
```

This is how you can write in ES6:

```
lastName = (family) => console.log("My last name is " + family);
x = lastName("Lopez");
```

2- Deceleration Functions: Functions are declared with the following syntax are not executed immediately. They are "saved for later use", and will be executed later, when they are invoked (called upon).These type of functions work if you call them BEFORE or AFTER where they have been defined. If you call a deceleration function before where it has been defined - Hoisting - works properly.

```
function Name(name) {
  console.log("My cat's name is " + name);
}
Name("Chloe");
```

Hoisting example:

```
Name("Chloe");
function Name(name) {
   console.log("My cat's name is " + name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In short yes you do have to define it before using a function, but you could use the setTimeout function for your delay which takes a string as the code to exectute:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    setTimeOut('openModal()', 2000);

    openModal = function () {
        $('#modal-box').css( {
            left: $(window).width() / 2 - $('#modal-box').width() / 2,
            top: $(window).height() / 2 - $('#modal-box').height() / 2
        } );
        $('#modal-box').show();
        $('#modal-mask').show();
    };  

});
```

this would work as the function is not called until after it is defined.

Comment: Your first suggestion does not work, since at the moment you call ` delay(openModal, 2000)`, `openModal` is still holding a reference to the empty function. The real function is only assigned afterwards, but it does not affect the value you already passed. Your second suggestion only works "by mistake". Since `openModal` is not declared with `var`, it is global. But as soon as you declare it properly with `var`, it won't work anymore, since `setTimeout` evaluates strings in global scope (and `openModal` would be local to the ready event handler).