# Async Await Node js

Tags: node.js

I am learning async await using node js

```
var testasync = async () =>
{

const result1 = await returnone();

return result1;
}

testasync().then((name)=>{
    console.log(name);
}).catch((e) =>{
    console.log(e);
});


var returnone = () =>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve('1');
    },2000)
})
}
```

It fails with returnone is not a function. What am i doing wrong? calling the function just by itself work

```
returnone().then((name1) => {
    console.log(name1)
})
```

Just calling the above code works

Comment: let test = await returnone should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a Javascript function have to be defined before calling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973461/does-a-javascript-function-have-to-be-defined-before-calling-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error because of [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp). Your code seen by JS would look like this

```
var returnone;
var testasync = async () => {
  const result1 = await returnone();  
  return result1;
}

testasync().then((name) => {
  console.log(name);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});

returnone = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('1');
    }, 2000)
  })
}
```

So the value of `returnone` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the function to the variable *returnone* at the end of the code, but you are trying to call that function before this assignment. You have two options to fix the code:

**Option 1**

Use a function declaration; this way, the function is hoisted and you can use it right from the start:

```
var testasync = async () => {
  const result1 = await returnone();  
  return result1;
}

testasync().then((name) => {
  console.log(name);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});

function returnone() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('1');
    }, 2000)
  })
}
```

**Option 2**

Assign the function to the variable before you try to call it:

```
var returnone = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('1');
    }, 2000)
  })
}

var testasync = async () => {
  const result1 = await returnone();  
  return result1;
}

testasync().then((name) => {
  console.log(name);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Make sense, I was just trying to rewrite some and forgot that the defintion of the function was after the call