# Why can JavaScript functions to be accessed Before they are defined?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I use a function before it's defined in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript)

As would be expected, the following code throws an error because `Foo` is not defined:

```
window.Foo = Foo;
```

Also as expected, this throws the same error:

```
window.Foo = Foo;
Foo = function() {
    ...
};
```

Curiously, this works just fine:

```
window.Foo = Foo;
function Foo(){
    ...
};
```

How is this possible? Isn't JavaScript interpreted line-by-line?

Comment: [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is parsed first, allowing your code to call functions that are defined later on.

Comment: Ah! I also found this right after asking: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ "Even if declaration is positioned last in a source, it will be evaluated foremost any other expressions contained in a scope."

Comment: Yes the script is parsed first. That doesn't explain why the two types of functions behave differently. The difference is in the evaluation of function declarations vs expressions.

Comment: The conclusion is is true. However, it fails to mention why this is possible and how function *statements* are treated .. (function *expressions* are different)

Answer (score 4):

Hoisting is only part of the story here.

First, to explain hoisting:

When you use `var` in a JavaScript program, you declare a variable. Wherever that variable is declared in a JS scope, it is hoisted to the top of that scope. JavaScript has only Global or Function scope; in the case of a function

```
function hoistAway() {
  console.log(a);
  var a = 5;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function hoistAway() {
  var a;
  console.log(a);
  a = 5;
}
```

As you can see, the *declaration* is hoisted, but the initialization is not. Thus, this code would log `undefined` on the console, rather than 5. However, it would be satisfied that `a` exists.

When you don't use `var`, the declaration is not explicit, so it doesn't get hoisted. Thus:

```
function hoistAway() {
  console.log(a);
  a = 5;
}
```

will result in an error message.

In your examples:

```
window.Foo = Foo;
```

`Foo` was never declared, so you get an error.

```
window.Foo = Foo;
Foo = function() {
    ...
};
```

Again, Foo was not declared, so no hoisting. For the record:

```
window.Foo = Foo;
var Foo = function() {
    ...
};
```

will not throw an error. However, only the declaration is hoisted, so if you did something like

```
var bob = {};
bob.Foo = Foo;
var Foo = function() {
    ...
};
```

then `bob.Foo` would be `undefined`. The special case of `window.Foo = Foo` is weird because `Foo` and `window.Foo` are the same in the Global scope.

Finally:

```
window.Foo = Foo;
function Foo(){
    ...
};
```

works, because function declarations (as opposed to function expressions) are also hoisted; both the name and the definition gets hoisted, so this would work as intended.