# JavaScript function and variable scope

Tags: javascript

Since in JavaScript functions are same as objects, they should have a similar scope in terms of where they are defined. However, the following code confuses me:

```
console.log(lateFunc());

function lateFunc(){
    return 'This function comes late!';
};

console.log(lateVar);

var lateVar = 'This variable comes late!';
```

In this case, `lateFunc` and `lateVar` are both define AFTER console command. However, this is what I got from `node test.js`:

```
This function comes late!
undefined
```

The first console recognizes the function that is defined later. However, the second one does not recognize the variable defined later. So I'm confused about why this is happening. Shouldn't they both have global scope OR visible only after definition? Can anyone explain?

Comment: The variable isn't defined later, it is *assigned* later. Think of it as definitions being processed before any code is actually run.

Comment: i think it is very clearly written here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887408/javascript-function-declaration-and-evaluation-order... hv fun

Comment: You also got an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript

Comment: Defining 'before' or 'after' is for variables and not functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the compilation vs expression nature of javascript language.

`function fun1()` is declared, so it exists since compile state.

`var fun1 = 'sth sth';` is an assignment expression, so it depends on the execution order.

**Source**

[JavaScript function declaration and evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887408/javascript-function-declaration-and-evaluation-order)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, this code...

```
console.log(lateVar);
var lateVar = 'This variable comes late!';
```

is actually equivalent to...

```
var lateVar = undefined;
console.log(lateVar);
lateVar = 'This variable comes late!';
```

which explains why this is happening. A function defined like this...

```
function lateFunc(){
    return 'This function comes late!';
};
```

is different and is defined in the whole scope.

Hope this helps.