# Closure returning undefined unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, closures, melonjs

I'm creating a melonJS game.

In my player entity - `game.PlayerEntity = me.ObjectEntity.extend({`, its update function checks for collision:

```
game.PlayerEntity = me.ObjectEntity.extend({
   var collision = me.game.collide(this); 

   if (collision) {
       if (collision.obj.type == me.game.ACTION_OBJECT) {
           console.log("NPCname: " + game.NPCEntity.init); //get settings from NPCEntity
       }
   }
```

Then in my NPC entity object, `game.NPCEntity = me.ObjectEntity.extend ({`, I want to return `settings.name` to the PlayerEntity above. So to do this I've created a closure `returnSettings()`.

1) `console.log(settings.name)` outputs "Lee" as expected

2) `return settings.name` outputs "undefined"

**Why is this?**

```
game.NPCEntity = me.ObjectEntity.extend ({
    init : function(x, y, settings) {
        settings.image = "wheelie_right";
        settings.spritewidth = 64;
        settings.name = "Lee";
        this.parent(x, y, settings);

        this.collidable = true;
        this.type = me.game.ACTION_OBJECT;

        console.log(settings.name); //works
        console.log("returning... " + returnSettings()); //works

        //closure to return settings values externally
        function returnSettings () {
            return settings.name; //returns undefined when called by PlayerEntity above.
        }
    },
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling the *returnSettings* function? In the above you have `console.log("NPCname: " + game.NPCEntity.returnSettings)`. And there is no need for the function, just do `this.settings = settings` and access the properties directly.

Comment: I'm trying to access game.NPCEntity's `settings` from game.PlayerEntities object.

Comment: Your first example is a syntax error, you're mixing a function with an object literal.

Comment: Now that you are at least calling it, the `returnSettings` closure is not a property of the `NPCEntity` object but the return value of the `init` function!

Comment: @Bergi yes I see that. I fixed above. still getting `Cannot call method 'returnSettings' of undefined`

Comment: I said *return value*, not "property of". Where are you calling `init`?

Comment: @Bergi actually I'm not sure where `init` is being called. I've looked through the melonJS API http://melonjs.github.io/docs/me.ObjectEntity.html

Comment: You really should go with Robs suggestion and just create a property instead of using a closure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49849/discussion-between-growler-and-bergi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shouldn't use a closure here
2. `game.NPCEnity` does not reference the instance, but the constructor function. If you set `this.settings = …` in the constructor function, you are creating a property on the *instance*.

You can access the instance with the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside your `update` function where you handle the collision, where it does point to the `player`.

To cite the tutorial:

> ```
> // call by the engine when colliding with another object
> // obj parameter corresponds to the other object (typically the player) touching this one
> onCollision: function(res, obj) {…}
> ```

That means you can access the enemies settings by `obj.settings` inside that event handler.

---

If you're not using that handler but calling the [`collide` method](http://melonjs.github.io/docs/me.game.html#collide), from what I see the return value of that function has a `.obj` property which is presumably the collision target:

```
if (collision) {
    if (collision.obj.type == me.game.ACTION_OBJECT) {
        console.log("NPCname: " + collision.obj.settings.name); //get settings from NPCEntity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can call the function before its definition because it's defined in *function name(){}* fashion instead of expresion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/261682/880114

But I don't see where you return that function to call it from elsewhere.