# PhoneGap App object functions not execut

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

i have very interesting problem in my Phonegap App for WP8.1. When i use function

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady(){
  **obj.alertFunction();**
}

var obj = {
   alertFunction: function(){alert('HelloWorld');}
}
```

nothing is happen, but when i use only **alertFunction()**; where alertFunction is

```js
function alertFunction(){
  alert('Hello');
}
```

all is OK. On Android is all OK and on Ripple Simulator too. only on Windows Phone device i have this problem. THX for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are using a `function` expression in the first case but a `function` statement in the second case for the alert. `Function` expressions are executed in a procedural fashion. Try changing the execution order:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
  **obj.alertFunction();**
}

var obj = {
   alertFunction: function(){alert('HelloWorld');}
}   

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
```

Here's a snippet illustrating the difference:

1. OnDeviceReady() executed on top:

```js
onDeviceReady();

function onDeviceReady(){
  obj.alertFunction();
}

var obj = {
   alertFunction: function(){alert('HelloWorld');}
}
```

```html
Nothing happens
```

2. OnDeviceReady() executed at the bottom:

```js
function onDeviceReady(){
  obj.alertFunction();
}

var obj = {
   alertFunction: function(){alert('HelloWorld');}
}    

onDeviceReady();
```

```html
Alert is triggered
```

If changing the execution doesn't work, you might need to rewrite your code into a `function` statement.

More reading:

- [Why can I use a function before it's defined in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/261682/541591)