# calling a function from view and controller

Tags: angularjs

Fairly new to angular so I think I'm missing something simple.  I have a function that I need to call from both a view and within the controller.  From the view I give the option to continue or start over so I have two functions declared as below.  both buttons in the view work fine this way.

```
$scope.start_new = function(){
//logic in here
}

$scope.continue_work = function(){
//logic in here
}
```

My problem is if it's the first time through I don't want to give the option so I have

```
//if the variable doesn't exist run the init
if(angular.isUndefined($localStorage.testVar)){
    //I've tried these ways
    //start_new();
    //$scope.start_new;
    //$scope.start_new();
}
else{
    $scope.active = false; //disply the layer which gives the choice
}
```

none of these fire the function.  If I declare it like this:

```
function start_new(){
//logic in here
}
```

it runs fine on the controller load but the button in the view no longer works.  The button code looks like this:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="start_new()" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn200">Start New</button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

here is the actual code:

```
stControllers.controller('WorkoutCtrl',['$scope','$routeParams','$localStorage','$filter','$location','Flash',function ($scope,$routeParams,$localStorage,$filter,$location,Flash) {

//set up counter background
$scope.strokeWidth = 20;
$scope.stroke = '#71d2f3';
$scope.background = '#eee';
$scope.size = 205;

$scope.show_list = false;
$scope.active = true;
if(angular.isUndefined($localStorage.currentWorkout)){
    //set up current workout

    $scope.start_workout();
}
else{
    $scope.active = false;

}


$scope.start_workout = function(){
    $scope.active = true;
    $scope.currentWorkout = $localStorage.userProgramTemplate[$routeParams['day_id']];
    $scope.setCount = $localStorage.setCounterTotal[$routeParams['day_id']];
    $localStorage.currentWorkout = $localStorage.userProgramTemplate[$routeParams['day_id']];

    //set up the workout detail
    $scope.workoutName = $localStorage.userProgramDay[$routeParams['day_id']]['program_day_name'];
    $scope.workoutDate = new Date();

    //workout progress circle
    $scope.currentSet = 1

    $scope.progress = $scope.currentSet/$scope.setCount;

    //start at first group
    $scope.workoutIndex = 0;
    $scope.groupCounter = 0;

    //start at first exercise
    $scope.exerciseIndex = 0;
    $scope.currentExerciseSet = 1;


    $scope.exerciseCounter = {};
    $scope.currentExercise = $scope.currentWorkout[$scope.workoutIndex][$scope.exerciseIndex];
    $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id] = {};
    $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id] = 1;
    $scope.currentExerciseSet = $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id];

    $scope.setProgress = ($scope.currentExerciseSet/$scope.currentExercise.sets) * 100;

    //reps
    $scope.reps = parseInt($scope.currentExercise.reps);
    //weight
    $scope.weight = parseInt($scope.currentExercise.weight);

    //create a storage variable to store counters in
    $localStorage.counters = {};
    $localStorage.counters['setCount'] = $scope.setCount;
    $localStorage.counters['workoutDate'] = $scope.workoutDate;
    $localStorage.counters['workoutName'] = $scope.workoutName;
    $localStorage.counters['exerciseIndex'] = $scope.exerciseIndex
$localStorage.counters['currentSet'] = $scope.currentSet;
$localStorage.counters['groupCounter'] = $scope.groupCounter;
$localStorage.counters['workoutIndex'] = $scope.workoutIndex;
$localStorage.counters['exerciseCounter'] = $scope.exerciseCounter;

list();
```

}

```
$scope.continue_workout = function(){
    $scope.active = true;

$scope.currentWorkout = $localStorage.currentWorkout;
    //set these values  
    $scope.setCount = $localStorage.counters['setCount'];
$scope.workoutDate = $localStorage.counters['workoutDate'];
    $scope.workoutName = $localStorage.counters['workoutName'];
$scope.exerciseIndex = $localStorage.counters['exerciseIndex'];//storage
$scope.currentSet = $localStorage.counters['currentSet'];//storage
$scope.groupCounter = $localStorage.counters['groupCounter'];//storage
$scope.workoutIndex = $localStorage.counters['workoutIndex'];//storage
$scope.exerciseCounter = $localStorage.counters['exerciseCounter'];//storage




$scope.currentExercise = $scope.currentWorkout[$scope.workoutIndex][$scope.exerciseIndex];


if(angular.isUndefined($scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id])){
    $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id] = {};
}

if(angular.isUndefined($scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id])){
    $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id] = 0;
}


$scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id] = $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id];// + 1;

$scope.currentExerciseSet = $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id];


//increment the progress bars
$scope.setProgress = ($scope.currentExerciseSet/$scope.currentExercise.sets) * 100;
$scope.progress = $scope.currentSet/$scope.setCount;


    //set the projected reps and weight     
$scope.reps = parseInt($scope.currentExercise.reps);
    $scope.weight = parseInt($scope.currentExercise.weight);

list();
```

}

```
$scope.next = function(){


//record the prvious info
$localStorage.currentWorkout[$scope.workoutIndex][$scope.exerciseIndex]['reps'] = $scope.reps;
$localStorage.currentWorkout[$scope.workoutIndex][$scope.exerciseIndex]['weight'] = $scope.weight;
$localStorage.currentWorkout[$scope.workoutIndex][$scope.exerciseIndex]['date'] = $filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
$localStorage.currentWorkout[$scope.workoutIndex][$scope.exerciseIndex]['set'] = $scope.currentExerciseSet;

    //increment the counters
$scope.exerciseIndex++;
$scope.currentSet++;
$scope.groupCounter++;

    //check for end of set
if($scope.currentWorkout[$scope.workoutIndex].length <= $scope.groupCounter){
    $scope.groupCounter = 0;
    $scope.exerciseIndex = 0;
        $scope.currentExerciseSet = 1;
    $scope.workoutIndex++;

    //check if it's the end of the workout
    if($scope.currentWorkout.length <= $scope.workoutIndex){
        var message = '<strong> Workour complete</strong>';
        Flash.create('success', message, 'custom-class');

        if(angular.isUndefined($localStorage.history)){
            $localStorage.history = [];
        }
        $localStorage.history.push($scope.currentWorkout);
        delete $scope.currentWorkout;
        delete $localStorage.currentWorkout;
        delete $localStorage.counters;
        //move workout into history and unset current workout variable

        $location.path('/home');    

    }
}

$scope.currentExercise = $scope.currentWorkout[$scope.workoutIndex][$scope.exerciseIndex];


if(angular.isUndefined($scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id])){
    $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id] = {};
}

if(angular.isUndefined($scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id])){
    $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id] = 0;
}

$scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id] = $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id] + 1;


//set up exercise progess   
$scope.currentExerciseSet = $scope.exerciseCounter[$scope.currentExercise.user_workout_group_id][$scope.currentExercise.exercise_id];

//increment the progress bars
$scope.setProgress = ($scope.currentExerciseSet/$scope.currentExercise.sets) * 100;
$scope.progress = $scope.currentSet/$scope.setCount;

    //set the projected reps and weight     
$scope.reps = parseInt($scope.currentExercise.reps);
    $scope.weight = parseInt($scope.currentExercise.weight);

    //set up some variable in local storage to use if we resume a workout
    $localStorage.counters['exerciseIndex'] = $scope.exerciseIndex;;
$localStorage.counters['currentSet'] = $scope.currentSet;
$localStorage.counters['groupCounter'] = $scope.groupCounter;
$localStorage.counters['workoutIndex'] = $scope.workoutIndex;
$localStorage.counters['exerciseCounter'] = $scope.exerciseCounter;
```

}

```
function list(){
$scope.workout_list = $localStorage.userProgramDay[$localStorage.counters['workoutIndex']];

//console.log($scope.workout_list)
```

}

}]);

Comment: Your third commented out example should work. What makes you think it doesn't? Does the code even get to that point? Can you show an example of this not working?

Comment: That's what I thought but I get:  TypeError: $scope.start_new is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.start_new = function(){
//logic in here
}
```

and then

```
//if the variable doesn't exist run the init
if(angular.isUndefined($localStorage.testVar)){
    $scope.start_new();
}
else {
    $scope.active = false; //display the layer which gives the choice
}
```

is correct.  I can't see exactly what is going on in your code, but I suspect you are calling the function just fine -- you just have some sort of race condition causing it to not work as expected.

Try putting a `console.log()` in your function to see if it is being hit when you expect it to be hit.

**EDIT:**

I'm pretty sure this is happening because you are using `start_workout()` (line 14) before it is defined (line 22).  Try moving the function declaration above the `//set counter background` and the original suggested solution should work.

Typically JS evaluates statements in a top-down fashion; there is a concept known as variable hoisting that causes straight up `function a(){}` calls to be evaluated immediately -- effectively hoisting them to the top of the code block.  This is why the function works fine when you declare it as a free standing function rather than attaching it to `$scope`.

You can find more information in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/261682/2457037

Comment: I do have one In there, it doesn't get hit.  I will post the full code in the am as I'm not at my computer at the moment.  As I said above I get the type error but I really can't see anything wrong.  I'll post the actual code (was trying to keep it clean). And hopefully you guys can take another look.  Thanks!

Comment: Edited my original response to indicate what I _think_ is happening.