# Can I not access attributes of 'this' when passing `this` through a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**NOTE: This entire question was based off a scenario where the issue was a syntax error; there was actually NO issue with passing 'this'. The question should be closed.**

For example, the following works:

```
$('.base-icons').click(function () {
   selectedIcon($(this).attr("src").split(/\/(\/*)/));
});

var selectedIcon = function(myObj) {
   console.log(myObj);
};
```

And prints the shortened string as expected. The follow ***does not work***:

```
$('.base-icons').click(function () {
   selectedIcon(this);
});

var selectedIcon = function(myObj) {
   console.log($(myObj).attr("src").split(/\/(\/*)/)[6]);
};
```

as it prints `undefined`. Why? Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Are you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/a/261682/5137782

Comment: _"For example, the following works:`selectedIcon($(this).attr("src").split(/\/(\/!*)/)[6])

var selectedIcon = function(myObj) {
   console.log(myObj)
}`"_ Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: @Ramanlfc Yet I've done it many times...

Comment: @JeremyBanks : Wouldn't the definition be automatically hoisted?

Comment: `this` and `$(this)` might be different things.

Comment: @PM77-1 https://jsfiddle.net/guv0dcbz/ , https://jsfiddle.net/guv0dcbz/2/

Comment: @PM77-1 The definition (`var selectedIcon`) would be hoisted, but the assignment (`selectedIcon = function...`) would not be, so he'd be calling `undefined()`.

Comment: Can you show a complete example with the problem?

Comment: @8protons The click event doesn't occur until after the assignment has occurred, and the click callback function already had a closure over the hoisted definition so it can call changeMe without issue. You're trying to use it immediately (before assignment) in the question, rather than waiting for a later event.

Comment: The first scenario **does not actually work** as you claim, and for that reason you question may be closed. Please try running it as-is -- it produces an error. The question you linked is talking about a function definition block (`function x(){}`), but you're using a function expression assignment statement (`var x = function(){}`) which has different hoisting behaviour. Please provide a full example, preferably as an executable Stack Snippet.

Comment: @8protons The timing of that code is entirely different than the code you've posted above, because of the use of events. It is a different question than the one you've posted above. Please update your question to actually demonstrate that scenario if that's the one you're asking about.

Comment: @8protons The code in the fiddle acts differently than the code above since you wrapped it in a click handler... Also having the same function declared twice means the second instance will overwrite the first.

Comment: @8protons IT IS TRUE! The problem you have is you can not have two functions with the same name!!!!!! Both clicks are calling the SAME method. Rename the seconds and magically the error goes away. T

Comment: Really!!! Let me change your fiddle and watch the magic. https://jsfiddle.net/j1t9mvur/

Comment: NO.... when you call it onclick it is defined before it is executed. When you have the code like you have it in your question above it is being executed before it is defined. Your fiddle is like apples to oranges. Two different things.

Comment: And because you did not show it, you got the answers/comments above.

Comment: Your updated code blocks both have syntax errors.

Please actually test your examples before inviting dozens of other people to test them for you.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Turns out it was my syntax errors. Thanks.

Comment: this is **NOT** the appropriate way to edit questions, you should flag for a moderator to remove if you want it removed.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson You're right. I had made that one edit in anger and frustration with some comments. Since then, I have learned to not take it personally and that people are just trying to help. Thank you so much for taking the time to check this out and editing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, the following works:
>
> ```
> selectedIcon($(this).attr("src").split(/\/(\/!*)/)[6])
>
> var selectedIcon = function(myObj) {
>    console.log(myObj)
> }
> ```
>
> And prints the shortened string as expected. The follow does not work:
>
> ```
> selectedIcon(this)
>
> var selectedIcon = function(myObj) {
>    console.log($(myObj).attr("src").split(/\/(\/!*)/)[6])
> }
> ```
>
> as it prints undefined. Why? Thank you.

`selectedIcon` is `undefined` when called at `javascript` at Question, resulting in a `TypeError`

Both examples at Question should return an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: selectedIcon is not a function
```

```js
window.onerror = function(e) {
  console.info(e);
  alert(e);
}

selectedIcon("abc");

var selectedIcon = function (myObj) {
   alert(myObj)
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't this return an error? I am calling these functions before they are defined. https://jsfiddle.net/j1t9mvur/9/

Comment: @8protons _"Why doesn't this return an error? I am calling these functions before they are defined."_ Because you are not calling the functions before they are defined at https://jsfiddle.net/j1t9mvur/9/ . For example, if you call `.click()` chained to `.click(handler)` an error will be logged at `console` https://jsfiddle.net/j1t9mvur/10/

Comment: Is it because the jQuery click happens after definition?

Comment: @8protons Yes, see https://jsfiddle.net/j1t9mvur/10/ where `.click()` event is triggered using `.click()` http://api.jquery.com/click/#click before the following functions are defined

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access attributes of `this` when passing `this` through a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attributes of this like this.

`$(this).attr("href");`