# Using async/await with babel - require("babel-polyfill") line not at the top in built file

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am trying to use ES2017 async/await syntax with Babel.
In `package.json`, I have

```
"babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }

//...

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0"
  }
```

The code I am trying to work with is

**src/index.js**

```
require("babel-polyfill");

async function foo() {
  return 10;
}
```

and my built file is

**dist/build.js**

```
"use strict";

var foo = function () {
  var _ref = _asyncToGenerator(regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            return _context.abrupt("return", 10);

          case 1:
          case "end":
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee, this);
  }));

  return function foo() {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}();

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { function step(key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) { return step("next", value); }, function (err) { return step("throw", err); }); } } return step("next"); }); }; }

require("babel-polyfill");
```

While running the *build.js* I get this error
`ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

**However, in the *build.js*, if I move the `require("babel-polyfill");` line to the top, it works.** But I can't manually do that every time.

So, how to do I use the async/await syntax with babel?

Comment: *"I am trying to use ES2016 async/await syntax with Babel"* async/await aren't in ES2016. They will be in ES2017.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since functions defined such as

```
async function foo() {
    return 10;
}
```

can be [used before they're defined in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript), Babel is moving it to the top of the file during transpilation.

To work around this, this try adjusting your syntax if possible:

```
const foo = async function() {
    return 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the `require()` call must come before the async function (and since functions are hoisted, and you set them up in the same file, the polyfill is loaded later).

Try to `require('babel-polyfill')` in an earlier stage in the module system. Something like this:

```
// A.js
require('babel-polyfill');
const foo = require('./B.js');

foo().then(console.log);

// B.js
async function foo() {
  return 10;
}

module.exports.foo = foo;
```

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. If I use the `var foo = async function () {}` instead of `async function foo() {} `, it works. Although, it still seems like a bug to me, since both syntax are valid.

Answer (score 1):

A different, and probably better solution would be to modularise your code:

- add an `index.js` which only exports the stuff you want to export and includes the polyfill
- add the real functions to small files that only do one thing