# Namespacing issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I'm trying to convert a regular function into function with namespacing. This is the regular function:

```
surprise();    

function surprise() {
    alert('TEST');
}
```

and this is the same function with namespacing:

```
var namespace = {};

namespace.surprise();

namespace.surprise = function () {
    alert('TEST');
};
```

I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: namespace.surprise is not a function`

Comment: Working for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h1hpdkb1/)

Comment: Worked for me on js fiddle as well.  Andrew beat me by 45 seconds. ><

Comment: @AndrewL. I just realised that I was calling the function from above it. I didn't know that's an issue? It's not an issue with normal functions without namespacing

Comment: What do you mean you were calling the function from above it?

Comment: @AndrewL. I have edited the code in the question to make it clearer

Comment: @user6793397 I've added a full explanation to why you get a typeerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call before a function is defined, you will get a `TypeError`. You must defined the function first. Before you define it, the namespace does not have a `surprise` function, and once you call it, JavaScript doesn't know what you're talking about.

The reason why normal functions do not need to be defined first is because:

> The function statement is magic and causes its identifier to be bound before anything in its code-block* is executed.

That's from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/261682/5647260). `function` statements **must** be defined with the `function` keyword and not stored in a variable like this:

```
var myFunc = function () {
    ...
}
```

To be treated in the described way above. Since namespaces store the function into a variable, they lose the capability of being used before it's defined.