# Code executing after return statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, return, evaluation

I found this short JavaScript snippet in the web:

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    foo = 10;
    return;
    function foo() {}
}
bar();
console.log(foo);
```

I would expect the contents after return statement in function *bar()* to be disregarded, and the variable *foo* to equal 10 at the end. To my surprise however, the console outputs something very different:

```
1
```

Now, when I remove the line after return statement

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    foo = 10;
    return;
}
bar();
console.log(foo);
```

The console prints out, as expected:

```
10
```

Can anyone explain me what causes foo to return 1 in the former version of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr it's due to how function expressions and function declarations work (also, function hoisting): https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

More detailed response:

Putting the following console.log's in the code will help you visualize what is happening, and I think answer your question.

```
var foo = 1;
console.log('0', foo)
function bar() {
    console.log('1', foo)
    foo = 10;
    console.log('2', foo)
    return;
    console.log('3', foo)
    function foo() {}
    console.log('4', foo)
}
console.log('5', foo)
bar();
console.log('6', foo)
```

The output is as follows:

```
'0' 1
'5' 1
'1' function foo() {}
'2' 10
'6' 1
```

So to your suspicion, console.log('3',foo) and console.log('4',foo) never get called after the return statement, which was expected. Your question now is probably "Why is my console.log('1',foo) assigned to the function foo() {}", which can be answered with the following SO question which describes function declaration vs. function expressions, i.e.

```
function foo(){}
```

vs

```
var foo = function(){}
```

[Why can I use a function before it's defined in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript)

Basically when `bar` is executed, the immediate definition of `foo` becomes function(){}, but the key concept here is this definition of `foo` is local to within the `bar()` function, and outside of `bar`'s scope it is still assigned to 1.

Another good read on function declarations and expressions: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: I accepted this as the correct answer because it's the most comprehensive. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcinWasilewski I'd reword that to it's the longest.

Answer (score 6):

Function declarations are hoisted to the top of their containing context. You're essentially creating a `var foo` at the top of the `bar` function.

The `foo` manipulated in `bar` is local to that function and doesn't affect the global context's `foo`.

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 2):

It is due to `hoisting`.

Compiler will basically turn that into:

```
function bar() {
    function foo() {}
    foo = 10;
    return;       
}
```

So there is a local `foo` before the assignment and you only overwrite the local. The function `foo()` would then also be gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the code is converted to;

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    var foo;
    foo = 10;
    return;
    function foo() {}
}
bar();
console.log(foo);
```

This is because JavaScript always moves variable declarations and not initializations to the top of the scope.