# Why hoisting works differently in variables compared to functions?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I have been reading some docs lately and came across some inconsistent patterns related to hoisting in JavaScript.

It goes as follows:

In functions,

```
function abc(){
 console.log("worked")
}

abc();
```

OUTPUT : worked

Also,

```
abc();
function abc(){
 console.log("worked")
}
```

OUTPUT : worked

This happens due to hoisting as in the execution context the memory is saved initially for abc.

**But the same doesnt happen in case of varibles and I was wondering why**

For example,

```
var a = "Hello"
console.log(a)
```

OUTPUT : Hello

**So why not the same in given below code?

```
console.log(a)
var a = "Hello"
```

The above code states "**undefined**"

when the execution starts for the above code:

1. a is set to undefined
2. then undefined is reassigned to the value provided that is "Hello"

**But that is not the case, instead it outputs undefined**

Why is that?

Thank you for reading.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript) for this question. That'll explain to you the reason for the behavior of functions.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
console.log(a)
var a = "Hello"
```

is interpreted as if it were written

```
var a;
console.log(a);
a = "Hello"
```

Why? That's the way the language is specified to work. Hoisting the whole initialization expression would create problems in many cases.

Comment: Yes so it should be "hello" right? as it has been reassigned, so why it is "undefined" ?

Comment: No, it's `undefined` because the `console.log()` call happens **before** the initialization.