# How to call a arrow function using addEventlistenr before initializing the arrow function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, arrow-functions

if I use arrow function  instead of normal function *flip* and do add addeventlistiner to it before initializing the arrow function then I am not able to call the function.

**

- Not Working

  ```
   console.log(cards);

   cards.forEach((card) => 
    card.addEventListener("click",flip));


   var flip = ()=>{
       console.log("card flipped");
   }
  ```

**output** : on clicking of the card it should give me the output as "card flipped",
but it does not do anything.

- Working

```
    var flip = ()=>{
    console.log("card flipped"); }

    const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

    console.log(cards);    

    cards.forEach((card) => 
    card.addEventListener("click",flip));
```

**output** : on clicking of the card it is giving me the output as "card flipped",

How do I call the arrow function before initializing it ?

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: "*How do I call the arrow function before initializing it ?*" **why?** What you're asking for is ***impossible***. Either you define the function *before*, or you use a regular function, or you create a new function entirely. There is no reason to *need* to do it as you've described.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call an expression function before the definition.

However, if you wanted to use a declared function instead of an arrow function with the 'function' tag, you could arrange your code in the way you described.

Example:

```
function flip() {
console.log('card flipped)
}
```

Similar question:

[why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript)