# Why can I use arrow javascript function before its initialization

Tags: javascript, function, hoisting

I checked out [Why can I use a function before it's defined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/why-can-i-use-a-function-before-its-defined-in-javascript). and It says I can use functions before or after initialization when using `Declaration Functions`. However for the case of `Expression Functions` I need to initialize before use.

But check my code please. I used `Expression Functions` and I can use it even before initialization.

```js
const x = () => {
  console.log('hello x')
  y() // why can I use it here???
}

const y = () => {
  console.log('hello y')
}

// later use somewhere in HTML
x()
```

Comment: It only matters whether `y` is defined when function `x` actually **runs**. So your code is **not** using `y` before initialization, because the call to `x()` is after `y` is declared.

Comment: @jsejcksn I don't think so. Because my case is about using function inside declaration while closures are more like declaration within declaration.

Comment: Yes this doesn't have much to do with closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you are calling `x` , at that time `y` is already defined. So it is not throwing any error. But if you want to call it before defining then it will throw error. Just like `console.log(y)` is throwing error before defining it. also take. a look at `hoisting`

```js
const x = () => {
  console.log('hello x');
  y();
}
console.log(y)
const y = () => {
  console.log('hello y')
}
x()
```

But if it is a function declaration then the function will be [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) to the top

```js
function x() {
  console.log('hello x');
  y();
}
console.log(y)

function y() {
  console.log('hello y')
}
x()
```

Note the changes in the error when you defined a function expression with `const` keyword

```js
const x = function() {
  console.log('hello x');
  y();
}
console.log(y)

const y = function() {
  console.log('hello y')
}
x()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is just a definition.

If you write `x()` before the definition of `y`, there would be an error.

```js
const x = () => {
  console.log('hello x')
  y() // why can I use it here???
}

x() // error

const y = () => {
  console.log('hello y')
}
```

Comment: You should also mention hoisting. The variable `y` is hoisted, but it's not initialized when `x` is called. `y` is already known when `x` is called.

Comment: I guess the I was confused usage with declaration. thanks